# Google Maps Polyline: Mark the two Polyline coordinates that contain the clicked LatLng

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, dictionary, google-maps-api-3

I have a problem in polyline of google maps.

I have a polyline from one points to another point. When I click on the polyline, I need the latitude and logitude of the two ends.

Please can anyone help me?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Geocoding Simple</title>
<link href="http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/standard.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function initialize()
{   
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(0, -180);   
    var myOptions = {zoom: 2,center: myLatLng,mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN};  
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions); 
    var flightPlanCoordinates = [   new google.maps.LatLng(17.772323, 78.214897),
                                    new google.maps.LatLng(28.46758, 78.027892),
                                    new google.maps.LatLng(29.46758, 88.027892),
                                    new google.maps.LatLng(20.46758, 97.027892),
                                    new google.maps.LatLng(17.772323, 78.214897)
                                ]; 
    var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({path: flightPlanCoordinates,strokeColor: "#FF0000",strokeOpacity: 1.,strokeWeight: 10});
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    google.maps.event.addListener(flightPath, 'click', function() 
                                                        {        
                                                        //attached click event now do your logic here       
                                                            this.getPath().forEach(function(el, index)
                                                                                    {          
                                    //infowindow.setContent('Point ' + index + ' : Latitude = ' + el.lat() + ' | Longitude = ' + el.lng());         
                                                alert('Point ' + index + ' : Latitude = ' + el.lat() + ' | Longitude = ' + el.lng());
                                                                                    });
                                                        });
    flightPath.setMap(map);
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width=100%; height:60%"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***UPDATE:*** Click on the polyline and starting and end points will have markers on top of them.

Here is one way of doing it [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kjy112/NRafz/).  Basically, using google map's click event property LatLng we get the Lat and Lng of the location of the mouse click in relation to the map.  Using that LatLng along with the points in the polyline we can determine if the targeted point lines on a straight line with two of the points in the polyline.  Furthermore, we'll have to use Geo distance formulate to calculate if two adjacent points in the polyline and the targetted point are on the same line.  If they are then by subtracting sum of point a and target and target and point b by the sum of point a and point b the distance difference should be closest to zero.  So using [this link's Geo distance formula and toRad() function](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) we are able to get the distance between three points.

**UPDATE #2:**

Q1: The if statement above basically extends the Number native function to include `toRad` function which converts numeric degrees to radians.  This is used to calculate the geo distance difference between two geo points.

Q2: The function `distanceBetween`

> uses the ‘haversine’ formula to
>   calculate great-circle distances
>   between the two points – that is, the
>   shortest distance over the earth’s
>   surface – giving an
>   ‘as-the-crow-flies’ distance between
>   the points (ignoring any hills!).

---

```
if (typeof(Number.prototype.toRad) === "undefined") {
    Number.prototype.toRad = function() {
        return this * Math.PI / 180;
    }
}
var markerDist;
var startPointMarker = new google.maps.Marker();
var endPointMarker = new google.maps.Marker();
var map;

function distanceBetween(lat1, lat2, lon1, lon2) {
    var R = 6371; // km
    var dLat = (lat2 - lat1).toRad();
    var dLon = (lon2 - lon1).toRad();
    var a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) + Math.cos(lat1.toRad()) * Math.cos(lat2.toRad()) * Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2);
    var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
    var d = R * c;
    return parseFloat(d);
}

function initialize() {
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(0, -180);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 2,
        center: myLatLng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    var flightPlanCoordinates = [new google.maps.LatLng(-27.46758, 153.027892), new google.maps.LatLng(37.772323, -122.214897), new google.maps.LatLng(29.46758, 88.027892), new google.maps.LatLng(20.46758, 97.027892), new google.maps.LatLng(17.772323, 78.214897)];
    var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: flightPlanCoordinates,
        strokeColor: "#FF0000",
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 2
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(flightPath, 'click', function(el) {
        markerDist = {p1:'', p2:'', d:-1};
        startPointMarker.setMap(null);
        endPointMarker.setMap(null);
        var curLat = el.latLng.lat();
        var curLng = el.latLng.lng();

        var allPoints = this.getPath().getArray();
        for (var i = 0; i < allPoints.length - 1; i++) {
            var ab = distanceBetween(allPoints[i].lat(), curLat, allPoints[i].lng(), curLng);
            var bc = distanceBetween(curLat, allPoints[i + 1].lat(), curLng, allPoints[i + 1].lng());
            var ac = distanceBetween(allPoints[i].lat(), allPoints[i + 1].lat(), allPoints[i].lng(), allPoints[i + 1].lng());
            console.log(parseFloat(markerDist.d) + ' '+ Math.abs(ab+bc-ac));
            if ((parseFloat(markerDist.d) == -1) || parseFloat(markerDist.d) > parseFloat(Math.abs(ab + bc - ac))) {
                markerDist.p1 = allPoints[i];
                markerDist.p2 = allPoints[i + 1];
                markerDist.d = Math.abs(ab + bc - ac);
            }
        }
        startPointMarker.setPosition(markerDist.p1);
            endPointMarker.setPosition(markerDist.p2);
            startPointMarker.setMap(map);
            endPointMarker.setMap(map);
    });
    flightPath.setMap(map);
}

window.onload = initialize;
```

Comment: @kjy112: replace var flightPlanCoordinates with var flightPlanCoordinates = [ new google.maps.LatLng(37.772323, -122.214897), new google.maps.LatLng(-27.46758, 153.027892), new google.maps.LatLng(29.46758, 88.027892), new google.maps.LatLng(20.46758, 97.027892), new google.maps.LatLng(17.772323, 78.214897) ]; ............. replace this code in var flightPlanCoordinates and see what happens..... it shows all the end point coordinates rather than coordinates of only that polyline

Comment: @kjy112: in the above code u have 4 points with latitude and longitude which form 4 polylines.....when i click on one polyline i need to get only that polylines latitude and longitude of both ends of that particular polyline...... here in the above code it shows the first and last lat, lng.........acutally i need lat ,lng of that particular polyline.......Please help me on this kjy112

Comment: @pradeepneo in that way you have to come up with an algorithm to check where the mouse click is and loop through all the points withiin that polyline and see where it is within the line.  goodluck.

Comment: @kjy112 : i have added the code once check that.....there u get all the points lat, lng when u click on any polyline......but when we click on a polyline only that lat, lng of both ends should appear ..... once check that and please can u do some changes to this code so that it works as i need ...... please kjy112 iam in great need of that please......