# How to change a polygon's edge upon clicking on google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gis

I know you can override the polygon's option by

```
myPolygon.setOptions(newOptions);
```

But what i'm trying to figure out is only change the color of one edge of the polygon instead of the entire polygon.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Here's a gist of what i'm trying to do:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager,'overlaycomplete', (event) => {
        const selectedShape = event.overlay;
        const selectedShapeType = event.type;

        google.maps.event.addListener(selectedShape, 'click', e => {
           // code to change the clicked edge of a polygon
        });
      }
```

Comment: You can't do that, the stroke of a Polygon only can have one color.  You can put a polyline of a different color on top of the polygon's edge.

Comment: related questin: [Google maps api polygon select edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22709428/google-maps-api-polygon-select-edge)

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to find an answer for this.

This one is based on another Stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5472967/11353945)

Here's an updated code:

http://jsfiddle.net/4sfw953h/

```
if (typeof(Number.prototype.toRad) === "undefined") {
  Number.prototype.toRad = function() {
    return this * Math.PI / 180;
  }
}
var markerDist;
var startPointMarker = new google.maps.Marker();
var endPointMarker = new google.maps.Marker();
var map;

var clickedPolylineLatLng = new google.maps.MVCArray();
var clickedPolylineArray = [];
var clickedPolyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
  path: clickedPolylineLatLng,
  strokeColor: 'blue',
  strokeWidth: 10
});

function distanceBetween(point1, point2) {
  return google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(point1, point2);
}

function initialize() {
  var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(0, -180);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 2,
    center: myLatLng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
  var flightPlanCoordinates = [new google.maps.LatLng(-27.46758, 153.027892), new google.maps.LatLng(37.772323, -122.214897), new google.maps.LatLng(29.46758, 88.027892), new google.maps.LatLng(20.46758, 97.027892), new google.maps.LatLng(17.772323, 78.214897)];
  var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: flightPlanCoordinates,
    strokeColor: "#FF0000",
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 10
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(flightPath, 'click', function(el) {
    markerDist = {
      p1: '',
      p2: '',
      d: -1
    };

    startPointMarker.setMap(null);
    endPointMarker.setMap(null);

    clickedPolyline.setMap(null);
    //clickedPolylineLatLng.clear();


    var latLng = el.latLng;

    var allPoints = this.getPath().getArray();
    for (var i = 0; i < allPoints.length - 1; i++) {
      var ab = distanceBetween(allPoints[i], latLng);
      var bc = distanceBetween(latLng, allPoints[i + 1]);
      var ac = distanceBetween(allPoints[i], allPoints[i + 1]);


      console.log(parseFloat(markerDist.d) + ' ' + Math.abs(ab + bc - ac));
      if ((parseFloat(markerDist.d) == -1) || parseFloat(markerDist.d) > parseFloat(Math.abs(ab + bc - ac))) {
        markerDist.p1 = allPoints[i];
        markerDist.p2 = allPoints[i + 1];
        markerDist.d = Math.abs(ab + bc - ac);

        clickedPolylineLatLng.clear();
        clickedPolylineLatLng.push(allPoints[i]);
        clickedPolylineLatLng.push(allPoints[i + 1]);


      }
    }
    startPointMarker.setPosition(markerDist.p1);
    endPointMarker.setPosition(markerDist.p2);
    startPointMarker.setMap(map);
    endPointMarker.setMap(map);
    clickedPolyline.setMap(map);
  });
  flightPath.setMap(map);
}

window.onload = initialize;
```